# How to test ElementRef in Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular8

I am setting styles to some divs from my component. My declaration is

```js
@ViewChild('listDiv', { static: false }) listDiv: ElementRef;
// listDiv is an html div element
```

I am setting the style as follows

```js
if ( this.listDiv!== null && this.listDiv!== undefined ) {
      this.utility.setDisplay(this.listDiv, 'block');
}
```

setDisplay method is defined in utility service, with renderer2 as follows

```js
setDisplay(element: ElementRef, display) {
    this.renderer.setStyle(element.nativeElement, 'display', display);
}
```

So if I want to test that `listDiv` has style `display: block` how should I go about it?

I tried the following but it fails

```js
it('showListDiv', () => {
    const HTMLElements = {};
    document.getElementById = jasmine
      .createSpy('HTML Element')
      .and.callFake(ID => {
        if (!HTMLElements[ID]) {
          const newElement = document.createElement('div');
          HTMLElements[ID] = newElement;
        }
        return HTMLElements[ID];
      });
    component.showListDiv();
    expect(component.listDiv.nativeElement.getAttribute('style')).toBe('display: block;');
  });
```

I am not sure how and what to mock if that is needed. Can anyone suggest a way to test elementref?

Comment: If you're confident that `setDisplay` in `utility service` does its job, you can call `spyOn` the utility service `setDisplay` method and then call `component.showListDiv` and then expect `utilityService.setDisplay` was call with `component.listDiv` and `block`.

Comment: This helped. I have now changed the tests to check if the `utilityService.setDisplay` was called with correct arguments. Thank you :)